# How to ng-repeat array of an object in object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, object

I have this data:

```
{
   "order":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "table":1,
         "foods":"{'foods':[{'id':2, 'name':'Nasi Minyak', 'qty':1}]}",
         "drinks":"{'drinks':[{'id':1,'name':'Teh O Ais','qty':1}]}",
         "waiter":"ali",
         "foods_status":0,
         "drinks_status":0,
         "created_at":"2015-07-12T00:30:52.637Z",
         "updated_at":"2015-07-12T00:30:52.637Z"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "table":2,
         "foods":"{'foods':[{'id':2, 'name':'Nasi Goreng', 'qty':1}]}",
         "drinks":"{'drinks':[{'id':1,'name':'Milo Ais','qty':1}]}",
         "waiter":"abu",
         "foods_status":0,
         "drinks_status":0,
         "created_at":"2015-07-12T00:51:43.552Z",
         "updated_at":"2015-07-12T00:51:43.552Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

I try to grab all foods `name` inside table like this:

```
<table class="table-bordered table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>   
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
                <td>{{order.id}}</td>
                <td>{{order.foods.name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And this is my `$http.get` to get the data:

```
$http.get("../api/orders")
 .success(function(data) {
  var order = data.order;
  $scope.orders = order;
 });
```

I managed to bind the `id` but I could't bind the `name` inside the `foods` array.
How to get the `name` inside the foods array of this data?

**Plunker**:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2oiOc06cZph4en8DJ18n

Comment: you need a second ng-repeat loop inside the order. `ng-repeat="food in order.foods.foods"`

Comment: why would you even return data like that from the server? fix the way the server serializes the data, don't try to monkey patch display a senseless data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need another ng-reapeat. Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <td>{{order.id}}</td>
    <td>
        <span ng-repeat="item in order.foods.foods">{{item.name}}/</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Another consideration is about the format of your JSON. this line:

```
"foods":"{'foods':[{'id':2, 'name':'Nasi Minyak', 'qty':1}]}"
```

the way it is, "foods" is holding a String, and not a Object. To make the ng-reapeat work, you will need to force JSON from string using

`JSON.parse(jsonString)`;

or change your JSON to:

```
"foods":{"foods":[{"id":2, "name":"Nasi Minyak", "qty":1}]}
```

Side note, why repeat the keys "foods" and "drinks"? Doesn't seem logic to me. Change your data structure to:

```
"order":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "table":1,
         "foods":[{"id":1, "name":"Nasi Kerabu", "qty":1},{"id":2, "name":"Nasi Minyak", "qty":1}],
         "drinks":[{"id":1,"name":"Sirap Ais","qty":1},{"id":2, "name":"Milo Ais", "qty":1}],
         "waiter":"ali",
         "foods_status":0,
         "drinks_status":0,
         "created_at":"2015-07-12T00:30:52.637Z",
         "updated_at":"2015-07-12T03:30:35.684Z"
      },
      ...
      ]
```

and use:

```
<td>  <span ng-repeat="item in order.foods">{{item.name}}</span> </td>
```

Here is a plunker with these modifications:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UVvCVzh4hbsEwolyWpDs?p=preview

Comment: Need your help. I just created a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2oiOc06cZph4en8DJ18n

Comment: Renan: I change my JSON data and updated the Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/8WawGrpVO6hzbkUrVZQ8 Still don't have idea how to get the foods `name`.

Comment: Here is a plunker that works http://plnkr.co/edit/snE9Em0tCKh0nUHIlTFn?p=preview.
Consider modifying your JSON file. Use double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks.

In your modified JSON file in your new plunker remove double quotations marks here

Comment: You didn't do what I said. If a key in your JSON is going to store an array or an object, you must not use double quotations on the value! Another thing, if you are going to remove the double key "foods", you have to change the ng-repeat.  I edited my answer to help you more

Answer (score 0):

Each `order` would be an object like this:

```
  {
     "id":2,
     "table":2,
     "foods":"{'foods':[{'id':2, 'name':'Nasi Goreng', 'qty':1}]}",
     "drinks":"{'drinks':[{'id':1,'name':'Milo Ais','qty':1}]}",
     "waiter":"abu",
     "foods_status":0,
     "drinks_status":0,
     "created_at":"2015-07-12T00:51:43.552Z",
     "updated_at":"2015-07-12T00:51:43.552Z"
  }
```

Note that `foods` points to an object, whose only key `'foods'` points to an array... whose first component should be an object. However, if you read more closely:

```
"foods":"{'foods':[{'id':2, 'name':'Nasi Goreng', 'qty':1}]}",
```

Notice the double quotes surrounding `foods`'s value? They mean that it points to a String instead of an object.

First, you need to delete the double quotes surrounding the values of both `foods` and `drinks`:

```
"foods":{'foods':[{'id':2, 'name':'Nasi Goreng', 'qty':1}]},
"drinks":{'drinks':[{'id':1,'name':'Milo Ais','qty':1}]},
```

And then replace all the single quotes with double ones, to make the object comply with the JSON object definition:

```
"foods":{"foods":[{"id":2, "name":"Nasi Goreng", "qty":1}]},
"drinks":{"drinks":[{"id":1,"name":"Milo Ais","qty":1}]},
```

Now, to get `'name'`, you need to access `order.foods.foods[0].name` instead of `order.foods.name`.

Comment: Still couldn't get it. I just created a Plunker. Hope you can help: http://plnkr.co/edit/2oiOc06cZph4en8DJ18n

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunker that works http://plnkr.co/edit/snE9Em0tCKh0nUHIlTFn?p=preview.
Consider modifying your JSON file. Use double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks.

In your modified JSON file in your new plunker remove double quotations marks here `"[{'id':1,`

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your data and it fix the issue you are facing.

Here is plunker link

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/nxBGMMyuNIzUOvQAu7YY?p=preview`
```